# Replace a range of elements in a vector with a value

Tags: c++, vector

I want to replace any value from a position `a` to a position `b` inside my vector.

I read about [replace function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/), but I have to specify the value that I want replaced. I need to replace any values.

For example if the vector is: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0`, and I want to replace all the elements from position 0 to position 8 with another value, how can I use that `replace` function?

Now I'm using a for loop to do that, but my program is very slow.

Comment: The fastest option would be memset I think. Or memcpy if you have different value.

Comment: @Teo Replace by what?

Comment: @LogicStuff I want replace integers with another integer

Comment: do not use memset, but STL Algorithms. as written by acraig5075 std::fill is a good fit. but check out the others as well (google STL algorithms)

Comment: @jonas_toth if you use C++17 with contiguous sequence concept yes, but I think otherwise memset is still better. Well I'm not an expert ^^

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel the algorithms will use memset under the hood if its the best option. But memset can only work on contiguus memory and is C. The algorithms are more general and as efficient, so less to remember but always full speed. i think thats worth it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) does what you want.

```
int newValue = 0;
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::begin(v) + 8, newValue);
```

Comment: But, is it more efficient then a for loop?

Comment: @Teo yes it is.

Comment: @Teo It should go without saying that you must measure and profile to see whether this is your actual bottleneck. Your architecture and your choice of compiler all have an impact. Prefer the std algorithms until measurements prove something more low level like memcpy actually gives a measurable gain.

Comment: @Teo Show some actual code because you must be doing something different to what your question is not clear about.